# Identify changes in time series (character) values and flag location of new value in corresponding dataset

Tags: r, xts, lag, quantitative-finance

I am working with a time series dataset with character inputs (specifically, future contract details). I would like to identify dates where the character value is not the same as the previous available date, and for those specific dates, identify which of the consecutive columns has that value. I have provided a sample dataset below. I have considered using `lag()` on this xts object, but I get an error:

```
Error in `[.xts`(x, seq_len(xlen - n)) : subscript out of bounds
```

Also my current approach is a bit brute force that I would like to avoid (especially since the number of corresponding columns vary for different datasets).

Purpose: I have a corresponding returns time series in the same format as the character time series. By identifying the corresponding column and date location [new location] in which this new character (contract detail) features, I would like to replace existing return in the first column on that date with new location's return.

**Sharing a sample dput output of character time series `tempContracts`:**

```
structure(c("SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", 
"SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", 
"SPU19-USA", "SPU19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", 
"SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPZ19-USA", "SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", 
"SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", 
"SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA", "SPH20-USA"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1567728000, 
1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568592000, 
1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 1569283200, 
1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 
1570060800, 1570147200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(21L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SP00.USA", "SP.1.USA", "SP.2.USA"
)))
```

**Sample dput output of return time series `tempRI`:**

```
structure(c(0.00295659400967452, -0.000872629691220261, 0.000100726912638294, 
0.00785891512466552, 0.00388982653805137, -0.00169370546773528, 
-0.00236269057182703, 0.00212999714436535, 0.000232693427461683, 
-0.000232693427461683, -0.00613601151530396, 0.00253900513908256, 
-0.00901586386319586, 0.00540587231028766, -0.001944091247152, 
-0.00561884290390235, 0.00494758931266404, -0.0137588161714284, 
-0.0196623961323645, 0.0107728408742762, 0.0133726493037134, 
0.00295659400967452, -0.000872629691220261, 0.000100726912638294, 
0.00785891512466552, 0.00325917345931082, -0.00179455699351827, 
-0.00243110601795671, 0.00209842695038276, 0.00029941614076634, 
-9.97954194730255e-05, -0.00550414199196148, 0.00253900513908256, 
-0.00901586386319586, 0.00540587231028766, -0.001944091247152, 
-0.00561884290390235, 0.00494758931266404, -0.0137588161714284, 
-0.0196623961323645, 0.0107728408742762, 0.0133726493037134, 
0.00298883607603528, -0.000805099003568621, 0.000134228188120922, 
0.00785444971143257, 0.0033236976786668, -0.00169370546773528, 
-0.00236269057182703, 0.00212999714436535, 0.000232693427461683, 
-0.000232693427461683, -0.00526667884051868, 0.00240344609471244, 
-0.00907650876598698, 0.00550263098282411, -0.00197611974611434, 
-0.00568212002020996, 0.00497781197372316, -0.0140212104959856, 
-0.019827124891334, 0.0105981832589173, 0.013540683361386), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1567728000, 
1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568592000, 
1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 1569283200, 
1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 
1570060800, 1570147200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(21L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("SP00.USA", "SP.1.USA", "SP.2.USA"
)))
```

**Expected output - discards the rest of the columns `adjRI`:**

```
structure(c(0.00295659400967452, -0.000872629691220261, 0.000100726912638294, 
0.00785891512466552, 0.0033236976786668, -0.00169370546773528, 
-0.00236269057182703, 0.00212999714436535, 0.000232693427461683, 
-0.000232693427461683, -0.00613601151530396, 0.00253900513908256, 
-0.00901586386319586, 0.00540587231028766, -0.001944091247152, 
-0.00561884290390235, 0.00494758931266404, -0.0137588161714284, 
-0.0196623961323645, 0.0107728408742762, 0.0133726493037134), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1567728000, 
1567987200, 1568073600, 1568160000, 1568246400, 1568332800, 1568592000, 
1568678400, 1568764800, 1568851200, 1568937600, 1569196800, 1569283200, 
1569369600, 1569456000, 1569542400, 1569801600, 1569888000, 1569974400, 
1570060800, 1570147200), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(21L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "SP00.USA"))
```

*Note: Change in value on 2019-09-12*

**Update:** a quick comment on the desired output: focusing on `SP00.USA`:

- dates where the value in `tempContracts` is the same as that reported for previous date, `adjRI` will maintain the default return values in `tempRI`
- dates, such as `2019-09-12`, where value is different to the previous date, then:

  1. flag the column and row in which the new contract is reported (on `2019-09-12`, `SPZ19-USA` is in column `SP.2.USA`, row 5)
  2. replace that date's return for `SP00.USA` with that provided in the flagged column and row (eg: `tempRI["2019-09-12"][,1] = tempRI["2019-09-12"][,3]`)

Much appreciate any help on this problem!

Comment: Hi Shriv, a bit hard to follow, when I don't understand what tempContracts is doing. Looking at your expected output, seems like you need, for every row in tempRI, the duplicated value? If no duplication, you take like the last value?

Comment: `tempContract` is an xts object that lists contract details traded daily. `SP.1.USA` is the first (to expire) contract details on respective dates, and `SP.2.USA` is the second (to expire) contract details. The first column, `SP00.USA` is an artificial list created based on certain criteria. I have an equivalent dataset for prices, which list corresponding prices of the specified contracts in the three columns for respective dates. I have to calculate the return of the artificial list `SP00.USA`, and the current `tempRI <- diff(log(price object))`.

Comment: To get an accurate return index for `SP00.USA`, I have to replaced days where there is change in contract in `SP00.USA`, with the correct 'returns'. To take a specific example, the contract changes from `"SPU19-USA"` to `"SPZ19-USA"` on `2019-09-12`.The return for the date in `tempRI` should be changed from `0.0038898265` to  `0.0033236977` (in `SP.2.USA`).

Comment: My final output (`adjRI`) is `SP00.USA`, after correcting the returns on dates where due to change in contract names, returns were not calculated with comparable prices in the `price object`. I hope this is helpful in clarifying the chain of different outputs provided above

Comment: Is the uploaded (dput) tempContracts correct? if you look at tempContracts[5,], it's all "SPZ19-USA"

Comment: I put the dput for `tempContracts` posted here, and `tempContracts[5,]` is:            `2019-09-12 "SPZ19-USA" "SPU19-USA" "SPZ19-USA"` ; note the middle value has `U` instead of `Z`

Comment: Ok my bad sorry.. I try and have a crack at it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202905/discussion-between-stupidwolf-and-shriv).

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. I have just posted the code I developed on the back of your inputs. Thanks for your help and taking out the time to review the problem!

Comment: Hi Shriv, no worries, glad it worked for you. It was a easy solution, took me a while to get past the SPU and SPZ =p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use lag. Do lag like this `tempContracts[,"SP00.USA"]!=lag(tempContracts[,"SP00.USA"])` to identify the rows which switches. Then using this boolean index, you can replace the values in adjRI. See below, I store it as test, and compared with the adjRI you provided.

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)

test <- tempRI[,"SP00.USA",drop=FALSE]
toChange <- tempContracts[,"SP00.USA"]!=lag(tempContracts[,"SP00.USA"])
test[toChange,1] = tempRI[toChange,"SP.2.USA"]
identical(test,adjRI)
```

Answer (score 0):

@StupidWolf - thanks for your input. It was helpful!

Notes:

1. As specified in the update, the dates where there in change in contract in column 1 (in the below code, these dates are flagged in `FlagRoll`), I want to identify in which of the following columns (only `SP.2.USA` in the sample, but the actual dataset has multiple (and varying) no. of columns to review) the contract appears on the previous date of change.
2. The code reviews column-by-column to identify where this is the case, and flags in variable `flagCol`. For those dates, replace returns in column 1 with newly calculated returns (calculation uses `tempPI`, which is price xts object in the same format as `tempRI`; cals are unimportant, but I have provided anyway)

```
#identify dates in "SP00.USA" (col1) where there is change in value
flagRoll <- tempContracts[,1]!=lag(tempContracts[,1])
flagRoll[1] = FALSE #adjust for value on day 1 from NA

#for the dates in flagRoll, identify the column in which the contract appears       
#method: 
#1. look at one column at a time (k is set to >=3 for my specific case, but can be set to 
#   k>=2 for a more generic sample)
#2. for each col, identify locations where contracts are same (flagCol) within the set of 
#   flagRoll
#3. for those dates, replace return values as difference in log of correct prices from 
#   tempPI [for ref: tempPI is the same as tempRI but contains prices instead of log 
#   returns)
#4. after all incorrect returns are replaced, save tempRI as adjRI 

for (k in seq(3,ncol(tempContracts))){
       #identify reference col for the roll
       flagCol <- tempContracts[flagRoll,1] == lag(tempContracts[,k])[flagRoll] 
       #note that you will compare with contracts second to expire or later, which start
       #from cols to onwards 

       #replace returns from identified col in continuous time series
       tempRI[flagRoll,1][flagCol] = log(tempPI[flagRoll,1][flagCol]) - log(lag(tempPI[,k])[flagRoll][flagCol])

       rm(flagCol) #to allow it to be reset for next k
}

#replace column j in adjRI with revised roll returns
adjRI <- tempRI[,1]

#clear variables  to run for another sample   
rm(k)
rm(tempPI)
rm(tempRI)
rm(tempContracts)
rm(flagRoll)
```